# Mocking list elements in Python using unittest Mock

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to test a function which accesses one of its attributes which is expected to be a `list` object and checks its content.
Example below:

```
def render_link(self, token: span_token.Link) -> str:
    if token.children is not None:
        name = token.children[0].content
        template = '<{}: {}>'
        return template.format(name, token.target)
```

So unittest would look like,:

```
children = mock.MagicMock(spec=list)
children.append(mock.Mock(content="content"))
mock_token = mock.Mock(children=children, target='target')
self.assertEqual(self.renderer.render_link(mock_token), '<content: target>')
```

I observe that `token.children[0].content` returns:

```
<<MagicMock name='mock.children.__getitem__().content' id='4365433488'>: target>
```

and not `"content"` as I specify when constructing the object by `mock.Mock(content="content")`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in a simple way.

Instead of using a magic mock for children, use a regular list instead.

Instead of `children = mock.MagicMock(spec=list)` we use
`children = []`.

Here is a code example. (Restructured slightly to allow it to run )

```
import unittest.mock as mock

class Renderer():
    def render_link(self, token) -> str:
        if token.children is not None:
            name = token.children[0].content
            template = '<{}: {}>'
            return template.format(name, token.target)
        return None

renderer = Renderer()
#children = mock.MagicMock(spec=list)
children = []
children.append(mock.Mock(content="content"))
mock_token = mock.Mock(children=children, target='target')
print(renderer.render_link(mock_token))
```

output:

```
<content: target>
```